# Cannot get the correct position of substring of a C++ string

Tags: c++, string, substr

I have created the following program in C++ in which I want to get differently the decimal and the hexadecimal value of a a string. The value of this string has the following format :

```
"123456 (0x1E240)"
```

So I tried with the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "123456 (0x1E240)";
    string sDec = s.substr(0,s.find(' '));
    std::size_t pos1 = s.find("x");
    std::size_t pos2 = s.find(")");
    std::string sHex = s.substr(pos1 + 1, pos2  - 1);
    std::cout << sDec << std::endl;
    std::cout << sHex << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

I get the decimal value correct but the hexdecimal value is received always with the character ")"
e.x. `1E240)`
I've tried to find the pos2 with rfind and find_last_of but the printout always contain the ")" character.
I also placed as pos2 the `s.length()-1` but again no success.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Second argument to [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) should be length of substring, not second position. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `substr()` takes as its second a `count`, *the length of the substring*:

```
std::string.substr(pos, count);
```

So, in other words, we should tell this function how much characters to grab, `count`, starting from the `pos`. You should change to this:

```
std::string sHex = s.substr(pos1+1, (pos2-pos1)-1); // calculate the count, subtract one
```

Otherwise, you were giving a result of iterator arithmetic `pos2-1`, the `14`, the value that corresponds to the index of the next to last character in `s`. Which, in turn, when passed as `count` yielded way more characters to grab then there was (considering that we start from the `pos1+1` character).

You may want to take a look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) or this [article](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) for more information on the `substr()`.